# Take text from an EditText in a ViewHolder Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

I must take the text contained in a EditText in a ViewHolder like this:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.editTextComment = (EditText) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
                String comment = holder.editTextComment.getText()
                        .toString();
                // String comment = new String("lol");
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
                SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                String formattedTime = dt.format(c.getTime());

                if (!comment.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.buttonPostComment:
                        addItem(comment, formattedDate, formattedTime, v,
                                holder);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

But my program crashes when I try to insert the edittext text into a String, why?

Comment: Post the logcat. Just by looking at what you have, I would say that your `editTextComment` is `null`. Try removing the `v` from `v.findViewById(...)`

Comment: I guess either `holder`, or `holder.editTextComment` are null when you call `getText()` on it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5nrtsYuC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the following code returns an `EditText`?

```
(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
```

My guess would be that it's just setting `holder.editTextComment` to `null`, thus rendering a `NullPointerException` upon doing the `.getText().toString()` on it.

Comment: you should have added this in comment and asked the OS for better clarity than making a guess work here..

Comment: I solved.....as said by ninetwozero, the code returned null, because the view v was incorrect. Thanks to ninetwozero and codeMagin

Comment: @CRUSADER: Ain't guessing if you check the OP revisions. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line

```
holder.editTextComment = (EditText) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
```

to

```
holder.editTextComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
```

This `EditText` isn't contained inside the `Button` that you click on which is what the `v` represents. If you only inflate your `layout` with `setContentView()` then removing `v` should work. If you used an `inflater` then you would use whatever `layout` you inflated in place of `v`

What you have is returning `null` for `holder.editTextComment` so you are getting a `NPE` when you call `getText()` on it.

Comment: I can't because this code in inserted into a getView in wich there is an inflater (v)

Comment: Then change the variable for the `inflater` insdie `getView()`. As it stands, it is probably using `v` as the `View` that was clicked because of scope